# File .htaccess not working

Tags: server, apache2, php

I have searched the web for this solution. I ´m using a custom .htaccess. This is the content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule rest/(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

But it is not working. It suposed to redirect to folder REST, but it only shows the local folder.

You can see it here: http://tedgamerz.no-ip.info:8080/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think your rewrite rule is written upside down.

You currently rewrite URLs from the form rest/myrequest to index.php?request=myrequest.

I don't understand clearly what you want to achieve, but if you want to rewrite urls like /myrequest to /rest/index.php?request=myrequest, you should wrote:

```
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /rest/index.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

If you want to prevent the directory listing, add to your .htaccess :

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: I think this is the problem now. Because before the problem was the misconfiguration in Apache. But i have moved the index.php to fix includes. I´ll check that later.